# Calculate datagridview Cell Sepratly based on data c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datagridview

Datagridview calculate Amount each cell Differently based on data from database if addition then addition should be done if subtraction then subtraction to be done.
i have created this method but it affects all cell with answer. only the above cell should be calculated.

```
    public void datagridviewone()
    {
        int addvalue = 0, subractvalue = 0; 
        ds = cs.Select("select ChargesProperty from FrieghtGridview");
        list.Clear();
        addition.Clear();
        subtraction.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
        {

            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == "Answer")
            {
                list.Add(j);
            }
            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == "Plus")
            {
                addition.Add(j);
            }
            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == "Minus")
            {
                subtraction.Add(j);
            }
        }
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                if(addition.Count > 0)
                {
                    for(int adval = 0; adval <= addition.Count-1; adval++)
                    {
                        if 
              (dataGridView1.Rows[addition[adval]].Cells[3].Value.ToString() 
               != "")
                        {

                                addvalue += 
        Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[addition[adval]].Cells[3].Value);

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (subtraction.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int adval = 0; adval <= subtraction.Count - 1; 
               adval++)
                    {
                        if 
    (dataGridView1.Rows[subtraction[adval]].Cells[3].Value.ToString() != "")
                        { 
                                subractvalue += 
     Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[subtraction[adval]].Cells[3].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                var finalans = addvalue - subractvalue;
                dataGridView1.Rows[list[0]].Cells[3].Value = finalans;  
                addvalue = 0;
                subractvalue = 0;
                finalans = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to do all these operations on the DataSet/List that you get before binding to the Grid.

Comment: i want to do all operation at runtime in datagridview